# Staggered treatment and predictions based on individual characteristics

Tags: r, regression, panel-data, difference-in-difference, treatment-effect

I have the following project in front of me:

Clients are going to get a bill informing them of a price increase (let's call them group A). However clients are getting the bill at different points of time.

I want to learn which individual characteristics eg age will make individuals to quit.

Then I want to use these learnings to predict the behaviour of other clients (let's call them group B).

I have thought that I should create a panel for clients of group A.

Quitted_it = (age_i + other ind characteristics_i) * days since they got the bill_it

Then I can predict the probability of quitting on individuals of group B, given their charactetistics and a number of days since they got the bill (eg 30)

Does it make sense? How could I compute it in R?